# Is it possible to label as TransitionPlot from Gmisc with counts?

Tags: r, gmisc

I have the following table:

```
   A  B  C
A  0  6 50
B 63  0 52
C 34  9  0
```

Where the row=A, column=B shows the count of the transitions from A to B.

I can easily plot this using the Gmisc package via:

```
transitionPlot(temp)
```

which gives me a nice plot with arrows from the states, where arrow thickness corresponds to the count proportions.

However, even digging through the documentation, I haven't really found a way to directly label the lines with the actual count information. I feel like this should be possible, so was wondering if anyone had any suggestions, either for this particular package, or if you have another package recommendation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry this isn't yet possible but you can easily add that manually using `grid::grid.text` option. You will have to manually search for where to put down the text snippets, I personally prefer having a table in the supplement for the exact data which is why I haven't added that function.

I also recommend that you start using the transitionClass as it's more flexible and allows you to do more, see vignette: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Gmisc/vignettes/Transition-class.html